# VHDL 8-bit adder with carry & testbench

Tags: vhdl, 8-bit

Heyo! 
I've been trying to get into programming vhdl again for some upcoming classes and tried to do an simple 8-bit adder and wanted to test it with a testbench. (I'm working with the Vivado Xilinx Software btw~)

---

I don't get any syntax errors, but it shows the variables as "U" (I guess undefined?)
Hope it's easy to see what I did (and why lol). Yea but I can't really find the problem??

**My code:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity addierer is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           cin : in STD_LOGIC;
           s : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           cout : out STD_LOGIC);
end addierer;

architecture Behavioral of addierer is


COMPONENT volladdierer is
    Port ( a    : in STD_LOGIC;
           b    : in STD_LOGIC;
           cin  : in STD_LOGIC;
           s    : out STD_LOGIC;
           cout : out STD_LOGIC
           );
end COMPONENT;

signal c : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0);

begin

    PROCESS (a,b,cin)
    BEGIN

    s(0) <= a(0) xor b(0) xor cin; --erstes s wird noch mit cin berechnet
    c(0) <= (cin and b(0)) or (cin and a(0)) or (a(0) and b(0)); --sowie das erste cout

    for i in 1 to 7 loop --Schleife um Stellen der Arrays durchzugehen

        s(i)    <= a(i) xor b(i) xor c(i-1);
        c(i)      <= (c(i-1) and b(i)) or (c(i-1) and a(i)) or (a(i) and b(i));    

    end loop;

    cout <= c(6);

    END PROCESS;

end Behavioral;
```

**testbench I used:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity testbench_addierer is
--  Port ( );
end testbench_addierer;

architecture Behavioral of testbench_addierer is


                SIGNAL a    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
                SIGNAL b    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
                SIGNAL cin  : STD_LOGIC;
                SIGNAL s    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
                SIGNAL cout : STD_LOGIC;

                COMPONENT addierer IS
                    PORT(
                            a   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
                            b   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
                            cin : IN STD_LOGIC;
                            s   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
                            cout: OUT STD_LOGIC
                        );
                END COMPONENT;




begin

U1: addierer
PORT MAP( 
        a => a,
        b => b,
        cin => cin,
        s => s,
        cout => cout
        ); 



    process
        begin


            a <= "00000000" after 0ms;
            a <= "00000001" after 10ms;
            a <= "01010101" after 20ms;

            b <= "00000000" after 0ms;
            b <= "10001001" after 10ms;
            b <= "00000001" after 20ms;

            cin <= '0' after 0ms;
            cin <= '0' after 10ms;
            cin <= '0' after 20ms;



    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Thanks already and hmu if something's unclear in my code!!
(and pls keep in mind I'm an total beginner.. xD)

Comment: `c(i)      <= (c(i-1) and b(i)) or (c(i-1) and a(i)) or (a(i) and b(i));` will cause bound check error (rangecheck should be enabled). `c` should be declared `signal c : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);`. `cout` assignment should be `cout <= c(7); `. `c` is missing from the sensitivity list.  Change the testbench, [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujkhk.jpg) (IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5 Signal assignment statement "If no delay mechanism is present, or if a delay mechanism including the reserved word **inertial** is present, the delay is construed to be *inertial* delay.", see 10.5.2.2).

Comment: (And the VHDL standard requires a separator (e.g. space) between an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier. See 15.3 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters. For example `10ms` should be `10 ms`.)

Comment: there is more than that: you placed your testbench stimulus into a process without a sensitivity list. Behaviour might be different between simulators, but I would strongly assume most will never call it.

Comment: @mfro All processes with no sensitivity list are run at time zero. If there is no wait statement then they are infinite loops. There is no difference between simulators as this is a VHDL standard.

Comment: Apart from problem of inifinite loop. The testbench process has 3 assignments to a/b/cin , the first two of each will be ignored. Futher assignments to a signal without a wait will overide previous assignments.